# KunstmaanBundleStandartEdition with GedmoBundle DataFixtures error

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.4

I'm using Symfony 2.4 with these two bundles. Problem is, that about 1 month ago it works both. Now it causes an exception during loading DataFixtures. It happens, that Doctrine ORM use UPDATE instead of INSERT for somehow. I've couldn't find the problem spot. Had anybody same problem?

Thank

Answer (score 0):

I've finnally solved this. It is a bug in GedmoBundle Tree generator, which apperas with Doctrine bundles v.2.4.*, so until they will fix this, better to fix doctrine bundles versions in composer.